# Why when I do an intersect analysis on a point feature class to a line feature class I only get 'one' point result?

Tags: point, arcgis-pro, line, intersect

ArcGIS Pro. I've merged my point feature classes of species and have gone to run an Intersect Analysis on these with a line (river) feature class. However, I only receive one point in the output and I know there is hundreds....

Comment: How do you know they intersect? Try [Snap](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/editing-toolbox/snap.htm), but backup your data first

Comment: Okay I'll give this a go. Thanks BERA

Comment: Point-on-line is often an impossible task. Instead use point-near-line with a suitable small distance tolerance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

line and points have very precise coordinates and therefore rarely match. Instead of intersect, I recommand you to use spatial join:

1. this will give you all the points with the attribute of the closest line.
2. you will have a distance field to check (with an arbitrary tolerance) if the point is near the line (or not)